# Getting a "Get-ChildItem : Requested registry access is not allowed" error

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

So a while back I made a mistake where I downloaded my Windows SDK on my F: drive which I don't use anymore and I'm now trying to do a clean reinstall of the SDK on my C: drive. Before doing that I want to completely clean my registry files of everything that mentions my F: drive because I've had problems with installations because the system keeps looking for the F: drive but doesn't find it.

I googled this issue and found someone saying that the most appropriate command to use here is to use powershell and then use the following command with it:

```
Get-ChildItem -path HKLM:\ -Recurse | where { $_.Name -match 'F:'} | Remove-Item -Force
```

However, after writing this command down in my PowerShell (I ran it as an admin) I'd get the following error message:

```
Get-ChildItem : Requested registry access is not allowed.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem -path HKLM:\ -Recurse | where { $_.Name -match 'F:'} |  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM:String) [Get-ChildItem], SecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Security.SecurityException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Please advise on what I need to do.

Comment: Run as administrator? Even with that there are some things you will not be able to see. Perhaps tack on `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`. However F: might catch more than you expect. I would _at the very least_ add `-WhatIf` to `Remove-Item`

Comment: By default, only `System` access to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM`. If you _need_ to search through any areas you don't have permission to, you'll need to grant your account access, although it's rare to ever need to go into these areas. As Matt said, tack on `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to suppress these errors.